# Windows XP hangs on bootup

Tags: windows-xp, boot

I am unable to get Windows XP to boot up. It stops on the screen after the progress beads. The hard drive goes crazy for a few seconds, and then the system hangs.

Safe mode and Previous known good config don't work either. A copy of my bootlog is below. CHKDSK was run and volume is healthy. I have tried replacing LSASS.EXE and MSVCRT.DLL.  I can't figure out what the OS is doing when it hangs. Any ideas how to pinpoint the problem? Some way to debug or error log to view? As you can see, the kernel and other core files load OK. I'm suprised Safe Mode doesn't work, actually.

backstory:
It used to be a dual-boot computer with Ubuntu, which I tried to convert back to single-booting XP. After using the Windows recovery console to fix the MBR, the system would no longer boot. After an eternity of repairing MBRs and VBRs, and using a plethora of recovery tools, I gave in and did a Windows parallel install. That fixed the boot issue, but now my original XP OS doesn't start. The new, parallel, Windows OS works fine however. I have them both listed in my boot.ini.

This is the contents of my boot log (windows\ntbtlog.txt)

```
Service Pack 3 1  8 2015 05:10:30.375

Loaded driver \WINDOWS.BAK\system32\ntoskrnl.exe

Loaded driver \WINDOWS.BAK\system32\hal.dll

Loaded driver \WINDOWS.BAK\system32\KDCOM.DLL

Loaded driver \WINDOWS.BAK\system32\BOOTVID.dll

Loaded driver ACPI.sys

Loaded driver \WINDOWS.BAK\system32\DRIVERS\WMILIB.SYS

Loaded driver pci.sys

Loaded driver isapnp.sys

Loaded driver vsflt53.sys

Loaded driver pciide.sys

Loaded driver \WINDOWS.BAK\system32\DRIVERS\PCIIDEX.SYS

Loaded driver MountMgr.sys

Loaded driver ftdisk.sys

Loaded driver dmload.sys

Loaded driver dmio.sys

Loaded driver PartMgr.sys

Loaded driver mvxxmm.sys

Loaded driver VolSnap.sys

Loaded driver atapi.sys

Loaded driver iaStor.sys

Loaded driver iteraid.sys

Loaded driver \WINDOWS.BAK\system32\DRIVERS\SCSIPORT.SYS

Loaded driver mv61xxmm.sys

Loaded driver mv64xxmm.sys

Loaded driver disk.sys

Loaded driver \WINDOWS.BAK\system32\DRIVERS\CLASSPNP.SYS

Loaded driver fltMgr.sys

Loaded driver MpFilter.sys

Loaded driver KSecDD.sys

Loaded driver WudfPf.sys

Loaded driver Ntfs.sys

Loaded driver NDIS.sys

Loaded driver vididr.sys

Loaded driver timntr.sys

Loaded driver snapman.sys

Loaded driver Mup.sys

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\intelppm.sys

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\nv4_mini.sys

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\HDAudBus.sys

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\yk51x86.sys

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\usbuhci.sys

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\usbehci.sys

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\parport.sys

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\serial.sys

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\serenum.sys

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\imapi.sys

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\ElbyCDFL.sys

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\cdrom.sys

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\redbook.sys

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\audstub.sys

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\rasl2tp.sys

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\ndistapi.sys

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\ndiswan.sys

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\raspppoe.sys

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\raspptp.sys

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\msgpc.sys

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\psched.sys

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\ptilink.sys

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\raspti.sys

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\rdpdr.sys

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\termdd.sys

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\kbdclass.sys

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\mouclass.sys

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\VClone.sys

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\swenum.sys

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\update.sys

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\mssmbios.sys

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\NDProxy.SYS

Did not load driver \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\NDProxy.SYS

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\RtkHDAud.sys

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\usbhub.sys

Did not load driver \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\lbrtfdc.SYS

Did not load driver \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\Fdc.SYS

Did not load driver \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\Flpydisk.SYS

Did not load driver \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\Sfloppy.SYS

Did not load driver \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\i2omgmt.SYS

Did not load driver \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\Changer.SYS

Did not load driver \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\Cdaudio.SYS

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\Fs_Rec.SYS

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\Null.SYS

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\Beep.SYS

Did not load driver \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\i8042prt.SYS

Did not load driver \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\kbdhid.sys

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\vga.sys

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\mnmdd.SYS

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\System32\DRIVERS\RDPCDD.sys

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\Msfs.SYS

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\Npfs.SYS

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\rasacd.sys

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\ipsec.sys

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\tcpip.sys

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\netbt.sys

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\ipnat.sys

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\wanarp.sys

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\afd.sys

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\netbios.sys

Did not load driver \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\PCIDump.SYS

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\rdbss.sys

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\mrxsmb.sys

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\usbccgp.sys

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\Fips.SYS

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\ElbyCDIO.sys

Did not load driver \??\C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\aslm75.sys

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\AsIO.sys

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\hidusb.sys

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\kbdhid.sys

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\Fastfat.SYS

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\Udfs.SYS

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\ndisuio.sys

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\rspndr.sys

Loaded driver MpFilter.SYS

Did not load driver \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\ipnat.sys

Did not load driver \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\rdbss.sys

Did not load driver \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\mrxsmb.sys

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\mrxdav.sys

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\ParVdm.SYS

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\StarOpen.SYS

Did not load driver \??\C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\AsInsHelp32.sys

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\srv.sys

Loaded driver \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\Cdfs.SYS
```

Comment: Here is the screen where it hangs: http://www.xpforums.com/attachments/147d1420704900-winxp-hangs-boot-img_20150107_211142798.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Windows XP has a huge advantage over Windows 7. XP has a very functional Repair Installation, when you can't boot into it it can fix XP so you can boot into it.  XP's repair installation installs the main windows files over the existing ones.

You can do the repair installation, it won't remove anything.

http://www.michaelstevenstech.com/XPrepairinstall.htm

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned ... The install CD does not offer the option to perform a repair. No idea why.

Comment: @timelessbeing  maybe you're not looking in the right place. It's not intuitive to find. You have to push ENTER as if you are going to install it, then the option appears. Can you take a picture with your phone of the screens where you think it's not mentioned when you follow the instructions of what to do at each screen  Here's another  page describing it with pics http://www.philscomputerrepair.com/Windows-XP-Repair-Install.htm

Comment: @timelessbeing see here http://www.philscomputerrepair.com/Windows-XP-Repair-Install.htm   take pics of your screen to demonstrate in your question how your screen is different from that

Comment: https://picasaweb.google.com/101268065625506391896/XP?authuser=0&authkey=Gv1sRgCLDE_83V9djddA&feat=directlink

Comment: @timelessbeing that is very strange.. I don't know if that is because A)Ms dropped it with sp3  b)maybe a cheaper cd like an oem or dell doesn't have it...I have an idea..

Comment: @timelessbeing well you could do some tests. Get an XP SP2 ISO see if it has a repair installation option don't go for the repair option, then slipstream it i.e. integrate SP3 into it making it an XP SP3 ISO, see if it still has a repair option, if it does, use it. And report back re slipstreaming an SP2 XP iso, though you'd need to have that and if you can't get it then you can't do that particular test.

Comment: That's a good idea, but I think I've come to the end of my patience. I think I'll just salvage what I can, and reinstall from scratch. Thanks barlop for your time.